# Load Data Infile Syntax - Invalid field count in CSV on line 1

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I was using phpmyadmin for ease of use and am using the Load Data Infile Syntax which gives the following error, - invalid field count in CSV on line 1. I know there is an invalid field count which is on purpose.

Basically the table has 8 columns and the files have 7. I can go into the file and change in manually to 8 by entering data in the 8th column but this is just too time consuming, in fact I would have to start again by the time I finish so I have to rule that out.

The eight column will be a number which is the exact same for each row per file, so unique for each file.

For example the first file has 1000 rows each with data that goes in the first seven columns, then the 8th column is used to identify to what this file data is in reference to. So for the 1000 rows on the sql table the first 7 columns are data, while the last column will just be 1000 1's, and then next file's 1000 rows will have an 8th column that says 1000 2's and so on. (note I'm actually goign to be entering 100001, rather than 1 or 000001 for obvious reasons).

Anyway, I can't delete the column either and add back after loading the file for good reasons which I'll not explain, but I am aware of that method is useless to this scenario.

What I would like is a method which as I load a file which fills the first 7 columns, while for the 8th column, to have a specified int placed in each row of the 8th column for each row there is in the csv. Like auto increment except, rather than increment each new row, just stay the same. Then for the second file all I need to do is change the specified int.

Notes: the solution can't be to change the csv file as this is to time consuming and it is actually counter intuitive.

I'm hoping someone knows if there is a way then to do this, possibly by having sql code which is both a mixture of Load File and Insert so that it processes correctly without error.

Comment: Too long, didn't read, sorry. Just post a sample of the data file and your load data infile statement...

Comment: If I do that you will give me answers which I already know won't work, hence I took the time to write out the methods which I know people might suggest but won't work. Plus this question has been asked before with answers that won't work for me. I'm trying to save time this way.

Comment: Read half of the question now, answer is simple to load the 8th column into a variable. Has this been suggested before? Post all technical info like I said, also what you've tried or what's been suggested. People like me answer a lot of questions here and out of experience I say to you again, that a wall of text very rarely helped to understand a problem better. And just very few, especially the ones likely to know the answer are willing to read much text. See, I read about more than 50 questions here per day. At some point you don't want to read anything that's not related to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate that. Can you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086782/import-csv-date-changes-to-0000-00-00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply load the 8th column into a variable, something like this:

```
SET @dummy_variable = 0; /* <-not sure if you need this line...*/
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE t1
(column1, column2, ..., column7, @dummy_variable);
```