# Import csv date changes to 0000-00-00

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
(Date,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,@dummy_variable)
Set dummy_variable = 0
```

Loads fine but date format shows reads `0000-00-00`

Date in csv is in the style `dd/mm/yyyy`, can't be changed in csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the date to a mysql format with `str_to_date`

Something like below should work.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@myDate,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,@dummy_variable)
Set dummy_variable = 0, Date = str_to_date(@myDate,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set Date = str_to_date(Date,'%m/%d/%Y')' at line 6

Comment: try now with sets on 1 line (doing it from memory as don't have easy access to mysql db at the moment)